# How to smoothly have a menu bar shrink as the scrollview is pushed up?

Tags: famo.us

I'm trying to achieve the effect of the header collapsing when scrolling up seen here: http://youtu.be/QXeFl093_FI?t=50s

I'm quite new to famo.us but here's a jsfiddle with what I have tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/jamalio/cy07xxs7/

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Utility = require('famous/utilities/Utility');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
var View = require('famous/core/View');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Scrollview = require('famous/views/Scrollview');
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var headerSize = 150;

var header = new Surface({
    content: "hello",
    properties: {
        backgroundColor: "#ccc",
        color: "#000",
        textAlign: "center",
        lineHeight: "9"
    }
})

var scrollView = new Scrollview();

var surfaces = [];

for (var i = 0, l = 30; i < l; i++) {
    var surface = new Surface({
        content: "test",
        size: [undefined, 60],
        classes: ["padding"],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            color: "#333"
        }
    })
    surface.pipe(scrollView)
    surfaces.push(surface);
}

scrollView.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

var scrollModifier = new StateModifier({ 
    size: [undefined,200],
    transform: Transform.translate(0,headerSize,0)
});

scrollView.justStarted = true;

var headerModifier = new StateModifier({ 
    size: [undefined,headerSize],
    transform: Transform.translate(0,0,1)
});

scrollView.sync.on('start', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    scrollView.justStarted = true;
    scrollView.startingPoint = e.clientY;
});

scrollView.sync.on('update', function(e) {
    if(!scrollView.justStarted && 
       e.position < 0
      ) {
        console.log(e);
        var currentSize = headerModifier.getSize();
        console.log(currentSize);
        var changeAmount = headerSize + e.position;
        headerModifier.setSize([undefined,changeAmount]);
    }
    scrollView.justStarted = false;
});

mainContext.add(scrollModifier).add(scrollView);
mainContext.add(headerModifier).add(header);
```

It's tricky because the scrollview.getPosition() doesn't return the position of the entire scrollview but rather the existing nodes. In the backend the scrollview removes nodes from the view and so it doesn't account for them.

In order to get around this, I'm getting the "position" on the "update" event and on update I'm calculating the difference from the original size of the header. The problem is when you drag the scrollview past it's boundaries, it stops sending events and it usually skips the last few, so instead of the position going back to 0, it stops at -4 or so, which messes with the whole logic.

Does anyone have a better way to go about this?

Comment: It looks to me like the fold only happens when your at the top and the second you scroll away from that it folds out of sight? It's hard to tell because it moves so quickly. Just want to be sure of what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I'll try to explain what I'm trying to accomplish in steps:

1. User scrolls up on scrollview
2. Header shrinks by the same amount of the scroll change up to a certain minimum
3. scrollview continues to scroll normally
4. User scrolls down
5. Header expands by the same amount of the scroll change up to a certain maximum

Answer (score 0):

I would do a full length scrollview and a draggable that pulls down from the top as you scroll. Just tap into the update to know the direction and how far it's moved and use the scrollview._scroller.on('edgeHit') to bring the draggable down when you hit the top. That doesn't really shrink the header as much as move it off screen but whatever. If you want the header to actually shrink you could use a modifier to scale it or just change it's size. If you want to keep the logic you have you could use the edgeHit events to reset the number to 0 or it's maximum but in general using get position on scrollview is a horrible experience that doesn't even usually give you what you want it to.

Comment: I wasn't aware of scrollview._scroller.on('edgeHit'), that would help a lot! I find often there are answers on stackoverflow with methods I haven't seen anywhere in the documentation, do people just grab them out of the source code? Or is there some hidden documentation I'm not aware of.

Comment: No it's just having a problem and digging into the code. famous github repo for the win.

Comment: Do you need a code example or do you think you've got it?

Comment: Unfortunately what you described won't exactly achieve my intention. Luckily I've almost worked it out and will post the solution. I tried scrollview._scroller.on('edgeHit') and it didn't work unfortunately, it might be deprecated as I'm on 0.3.0-rc, so I wouldn't recommend using this solution even if it did manage to solve the issue on an older build of famo.us. That's part of the danger of using "private" methods I guess.

Comment: Your right in the version your using it was changed to 'onEdge' they also added on 'offEdge'